# What happen if hascode function is false while equal function is true

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I am thinking about a question if hashcode function is false but equal function is true, what will happen? For example:

```java
public class Demo {

    private int age;

    private String name;

    //getter
    //setter

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Demo demo = (Demo) o;
        return age == demo.age &&
                Objects.equals(name, demo.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(age, name)
                + (new Random().nextInt(1000));
    }
}
```

Comment: The hash code isn't false, you just have different hash codes for equal objects.

Comment: What will happen is if you try and put such an object in a hashset, or as the key in a hashmap, the container will not work properly.

Comment: It doesn't matter unless you do something that requires equal objects to have equal hashes. Have you tried adding your objects to a HashSet, for example?

Answer (score 0):

What will happen is that instances of the `Demo` class will behave incorrectly when used as hash keys.

Here is one example of what will happen.

```
Demo demo = new Demo(...);
HashSet<Demo> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(demo);
System.out.println(set.contains(demo));  // will print false 99.9% of the time.
```

In other words, the `HashSet` will lose track elements from the perspective of the `contains` method.  (But they will still be there if you iterate the set.  And you will probably be able to add the same `Demo` object twice ... leading to the set containing duplicates.)